# Is it possible to handle GSM call in IOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am making an iOS application.Is it possible to automatically disable the GSM call while the application is active?

Comment: No you can not do this on non-jail broken iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been no official SDK for handling calls or blocking calls in IOS SDK. Apple does not encourage you to do so.